# Why does this Code cause the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

Here's a piece of code I wrote for cleaning A string of unwanted chars and double spacing.
However, I seem to have misunderstood memory management somewhere and it keeps causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. The Code works fine functionally when the release statements are removed but that would cause memory leaks.

```
-(NSString*) cleaningString:(NSString*) input  {
NSCharacterSet* wantedCharacters=[[NSCharacterSet alloc] init];

   wantedCharacters=[ NSCharacterSet    
 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"];


NSString* cleanStringOutput=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString* currentLetter =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
NSRange unwantedCharacters=[currentLetter rangeOfCharacterFromSet:wantedCharacters];

for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    currentLetter=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[input characterAtIndex:i]];
    unwantedCharacters=[currentLetter rangeOfCharacterFromSet:wantedCharacters];
    doubleSpace=YES;
    if (i<input.length-1) {
        if (([currentLetter isEqualToString:@" "])&&([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[input characterAtIndex:i+1]] isEqualToString:@" "])) {
            doubleSpace=NO;}
    }
    else {
        if ([currentLetter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            doubleSpace=NO;
        }
    }
    if ((unwantedCharacters.location!=NSNotFound)&&(doubleSpace))
    {
        cleanStringOutput=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", cleanStringOutput, currentLetter];
    }
}
if (cleanStringOutput.length>0){
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[cleanStringOutput characterAtIndex:0]] isEqualToString:@" "]){
        cleanStringOutput=[cleanStringOutput substringFromIndex:1];
    }
}

[currentLetter release];
[wantedCharacters release];
[cleanStringOutput autorelease];
return cleanStringOutput;
}
```

Please forgive me if I just asked something painfully obvious.

P.S. And another question. Is it necessary to release the NSRange?

Comment: my advice--> have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html this will help you in the long run..

Comment: You have a fundamental problem and it can be very illustrative for others to understand what it is. This isn't simply a "fix my codz" question. I don't think it should have been down voted.It looks like Warren Burton identified it for you.

Comment: I just didn't realise that returned objects are autorelease. I had some experience with java but not with retain and release memory management...

Comment: It isn't autoreleased by virtue of being returned. You have to se it up to be autoreleased, if that's what you want or need. typically, you do want returned items to be autoreleased.

Comment: FYI : Not _all_ returned objects are autoreleased - for example `mutableCopy` returns objects you own (and therefore have to release yourself). The rule of thumb - if the method is `aloc/init`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or `new` you own it and have to release it. Otherwise, it's autoreleased. When you have got more of an understanding of reference counting nd memory management, I heartily recommend starting to use ARC - it deals with most of this for you :)

Comment: PS You don't have to release an `NSRange` - it's not an object :)

Comment: Ah thanks. All the tutorials I took didn't really make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here

```
NSCharacterSet* wantedCharacters=[[NSCharacterSet alloc] init];

   wantedCharacters=[ NSCharacterSet    
 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"];
```

You discard your original object and replace it with an autoreleased one

Which will crash when you call

```
[wantedCharacters release];
```

Do this

```
NSCharacterSet* wantedCharacters=[ NSCharacterSet    
 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"];
```

and forget the last

```
[wantedCharacters release];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to objective C's memory management so i didn't realise that the return statement is autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code that causes you to lose the reference to the allocated objects, and an example will follow, but a few things:

1. The easiest solution for all of them, is to use `autorelease` wherever you call `alloc` (and remove the `release` for those objects), for example:

   ```
   NSString* cleanStringOutput=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""] autorelease];
   ```
2. When you create a variable only to assign to it later, there is no need to allocate, for example:

   ```
   NSCharacterSet* wantedCharacters; // no need for alloc here
   wantedCharacters=[ NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"];
   ```
3. In general - if you didn't allocate the object, you don't release it.

Comment: Applying autorelease and not properly learning memory management isn't a good long-term fix IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentLetter=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[input characterAtIndex:i]];
```

Returns an autoreleased string - no need to alloc/init it above.

```
NSString* currentLetter =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
```

So calling

```
[currentLetter release];
```

Will probably cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You alloc/init a `wantedCharacters` object, then reassign it using a convenience function. The reassignment creates a zombie with the first object.

The convenience function puts the new object instance into the autorelease pool.

Then you call release. Since it was only retained once, it gets deallocated.

Later, the autorelease pool calls release on it, but it has already been deallocated. This causes the crash.